# UIImageView has wrong frame when bold text enabled in accessibility

Tags: objective-c, uiaccessibility

I have an `UIImageView` which trailing edge is anchored to other view's leading edge.

However when I enable bold text in accessibility settings on iPhone, the image view's size is 1pt larger which makes image render in a wrong position.

Is it UIKit bug?

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];

[self.containerView addSubview:self.imageView];

[self.imageView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[self.imageView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[self.imageView setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[self.imageView setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];

// .. create constraints here ...
```

[image: Inspector]